# Python swig call with share library with another share library

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm writing a python wrapper to a C++ program in Linux with SWIG.

1. the C++ program will use a share library named `AAA` (linked dynamically). the executable compiled from this C++ program code, it works well.
2. With tutorial from SWIG , I am manage to write an interface and compile with xxx_wrap.cxx file, linked with `AAA` share library. this works well in most part, becuse , in python , import xxx, it works well, I can call function in the program, like xxx.say_hi().(functions inside say_hi() from share library `AAA` works fine).
3. The tricky thing is , when I call xxx.say_bye(), the say_bye() function will call functions from share library `AAA` (linked dynamically), and these function will try to load another dynamic share library in a predefined place (like /tmp/abc/yyy.so)

   `Failed to load yyy.so due to yyy.so: undefied symbol: ___gxx_personality_v0`

So ,my question is, does SWIG support such secondary level of dynamic share library loading ? using CentOS.6.4  , swig version: 1.3.40, boost: 1.46.1

### Thanks in advance.

Update:

after a digging , the yyyy.so was compiled from GCC, while I am using g++ to compile the C++ extension. After recompiled `yyyy.so` with g++, now the error is  more clear:

```
symbol lookup error: /tmp/abc/yyyy.so: undefined symbo: ABC
```

The `ABC` is a symbol defined in a header file used to compile `yyyy.so`, however , it should be included in share library `AAA`

Comment: It seems like you are trying to load a c++ library from a c wrapper. It is important to tell SWIG that it is c++.